# How do I make it possible for SSRS 2008 reports to be viewed by everyone on the web without logging in?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, authentication, reporting-services

I have SSRS setup and working fine. I can even access them from a web browser. The only problem is that it requires me to log in every time I want to review a report. I need anonymous users to be able to view these reports. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx), it states that anonymous access is no longer supported in SSRS2008, but can still be enabled. What would be easier though is just adding the ssrs site to your local intranet zone in IE, it will then log in automatically.

[post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I've found for my uses of it is to set up automated subscriptions where SSRS pushes the reports to a file share at regular intervals, then I have a web-app front end that has access to the file share where the reports are pushed and the web app dynamically generates a front end for whatever reports are on that file share.  This can be fairly easy to design and set up as long as you don't need the reports to be regenerated on the fly, which gets a bit more involved.